# 0 rows affected SQL query message

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table in my database in eclipse:

```
Recipe = (idR, recipeTitle, prepText, cuisineType, mealType)
Ingredient = (idI, ingrDesc)
RecipIngr = (idR*, idI*)
```

and I'm trying to display the title of the Recipe containing the fewest ingredients. Here is my query so far:

```
  SELECT recipetitle, COUNT(*)
  FROM recipe
  GROUP BY recipetitle
  HAVING COUNT(recipetitle) =
  (SELECT MAX(COUNT(ingrdesc))
  FROM ingredient
  GROUP BY recipetitle);
```

This shows "0 rows affected" so I have no idea what i'm doing wrong.
Any help?

Comment: What database engine do you use? SQL Server, MySQL, any other?

Comment: just using eclipse atm, sorry I should have said

Comment: Eclipse is just a tool, not a database.

Comment: Whoops, I guess that my comment made me look like a tool :L I guess i'm using SQL server then

Comment: You have to quess what database you use? That's not good way of writing a program ...

Comment: Easy now my friend, I'm a beginner so I'm just learning my way around. Any help with the query though?

Comment: What if there are multiple recipes with the lowest number of ingredients? Do you want to pick an arbitrary one, pick the first/last alphabetically, or show all of them? Also if you want the one(s) with the *fewest* ingredients, why are you using `MAX(COUNT())`? I suspect this will give you the one(s) with the *most* ingredients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either to select the first match, or all matches, depending on what you need - for MSSQL.

First:

```
SELECT TOP 1 RecipeTitle      = R.recipeTitle
       ,IngredientCount = COUNT(*)
FROM   Recipe R
INNER JOIN RecipIngr RI ON R.idR = RI.idR
INNER JOIN Ingredient I ON RI.idI = I.idI
    GROUP BY R.recipeTitle
```

All:

```
SELECT dtbl.RecipeTitle
FROM (SELECT RecipeTitle      = R.recipeTitle
       ,IngredientCount = COUNT(*)
           ,rank = rank() OVER (Partition BY R.recipeTitle ORDER BY COUNT(*))
FROM   Recipe R
INNER JOIN RecipIngr RI ON R.idR = RI.idR
INNER JOIN Ingredient I ON RI.idI = I.idI
    GROUP BY R.recipeTitle) dtbl
WHERE dtbl.rank = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to `JOIN` your tables to count number of ingredients for every recipe:

```
SELECT
    r.recipeTitle,
    COUNT(*) AS nbOfIng
FROM
    recipe r
JOIN
    RecipIngr ri ON r.idR = ri.idR
GROUP BY
    r.idR, r.recipeTitle
HAVING
    nbOfIng = (
        SELECT
            MAX(COUNT(*))
        FROM
            recipe r2
        JOIN
            RecipIngr ri2 ON r2.idR = ri2.idR
        GROUP BY
            r2.idR
)
```

However, I'm not 100% sure if that's gonna work, because I don't know what database engine you're using.